# Pipeling hadoop map reduce jobs

Tags: java, programming-languages, hadoop, mapreduce

I have five map reduce that I am running each separately. I want to pipeline them all together. So, output of one job goes to next job. Currently, I wrote shell script to execute them all. Is there a way to write this in java? Please provide an example.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find [JobControl](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/mapred_tutorial.html#JobControl) to be the simplest method for chaining these jobs together. For more complex workflows, I'd recommend checking out [Oozie](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/oozie/).

Answer (score 2):

Hi 
I had similar requirement 
One way to do this is

after submitting first job  execute following

```
Job job1 = new Job( getConf() );
job.waitForCompletion( true );
```

and then check for status using

```
if(job.isSuccessful()){
    //start another job with different Mapper.
    //change config
    Job job2 = new Job( getConf() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oozie is the solution for you. You can submit map-reduce types of jobs, hive jobs, pig jobs, system commands etc through Oozie's action tags.

It even has a co-ordinator which acts as a cron for your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is [Cascading](http://www.cascading.org/), which also provides an abstraction layer on top of Hadoop: itseems to provide a similar combination of working-closely-with-Hadoop-concepts yet letting-hadoop-do-the-M/R-heavy lifting that one gets using Oozie workflows calling Pig scripts.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, I think Oozie will be good. Oozie is a workflow scheduler in which you can write different actions(can be map-reduce, java, shell, etc) to perform some compute, transformation, enrichment, etc. For this case :

action A : i/p input o/p a

action B : i/p a o/p b

action C : i/p b o/p c(final output)

You can finally persist c in HDFS, and can decide to persist or delete intermediate outputs.

If you want to do the computation done by all three actions in a single one then you can use Cascading. You can understand better about Cascading by their official documentation, and you can also refer my blog on same : https://tech.flipkart.com/expressing-etl-workflows-via-cascading-192eb5e7d85d