# Hadoop map/reduce chaining

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to chain 2 Map/Reduce jobs. I am trying to use JobControl to achieve the same. My problem is -

JobControl needs org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.Job which in turn needs org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf which is deprecated. How do I get around this problem to chain my Map/Reduce?

Anyone has any better ideas for chaining (other than Cascading).

Comment: I have the same problem and I am wondering what you did to solve this? I'd preferably just like to use hadoop package instead of using a new one (and classes which are not deprecated :) )

Comment: I ended up not using any chaining.. Turns out I was complicating my issue..  I did however resort to using the deprecated JobConf for a different task, because I couldnt get to the task logs any other way.

Comment: Why don’t you share your solution? Answer on your own question and accept that answer as the answer to your question.

Comment: @Gumbo: I don't have a solution because I did not need any chaining.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pipeling hadoop map reduce jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939979/pipeling-hadoop-map-reduce-jobs)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Riffle](https://github.com/cwensel/riffle), it allows you to chain arbitrary processes together (anything you stick its Annotations on).

It has a rudimentary dependency scheduler, so it will order and execute your jobs for you. And it's Apache licensed. Its also on the [Conjars repo](http://conjars.org/riffle) if you're a maven user.

I'm the author, and wrote it so Mahout and other custom applications would be able to have a common tool that was also compatible with Cascading Flows.

I'm also the author of [Cascading](http://www.cascading.org/). But MapReduceFlow + Cascade in Cascading works quite well for most raw MR job chaining.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera has a workflow tool called [Oozie](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2010/11/better-workflow-management-in-cdh-with-oozie-2/) that can help with this sort of chaining. Might be overkill for just getting one job to run after another.